# Long exact sequence of homotopy group

Tags: algebraic-topology, exact-sequence, higher-homotopy-groups

> $\pi_1(X,x_0)\xrightarrow{j_*}\pi_1(X,A,x_0)\xrightarrow{\partial}\pi_0(A,x_0)\xrightarrow{i_*}\pi_0(X,x_0)$ is exact.

Here, I interpreted $I^0 = \{1\}$.

$\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}$**Exactness at $\pi_1(X,A,x_0)$** : $[f]\in\pi_1(X,x_0,x_0$) then $f:(I,\partial I,\{0\})\to (X,x_0,x_0)$. Hence, $\partial(j\circ f):\{1\}\to \{x_0\}$ which is a constant map. Hence, $\im j_*\subset\ker\partial$. Let $[g]\in\pi_1(X,A,x_0)$ such that $\partial g = 0$. $g:(I,\partial I,\{0\})\to(X,A,x_0)$ and restiction on $\{1\}$ is $g:\{1\}\to \{x_1\}\subset A$ is always a constant map. Here, I think $\{1\}\mapsto \{x_0\}$ so that we can consider $g$ as an element of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$. But how?

**Exactness at $\pi_0(A,x_0)$** : ???

1. Does my interpretation $I^0 =\{1\}$ correct?
2. How can show $\ker\partial\subset\im j_*$ in during the proof of exactness at $\pi_1(X,A,x_0)$?
3. How can I show the exactness at $\pi_0(A,x_0)$? $\ker i_* = \im\partial $? what is $\ker i_*$ in $\pi_0$ even mean?

I believe I'm missing something basic. I don't know what to show. Could you help?

Comment: I don't see an $I^0$ anywhere to be interpreted.

Comment: @Randall In the definition of relative homotopy group $\pi_n(X,A,x_0)$, any element is represented by $(I^n,\partial I^n,J^{n-1})\to (X,A,x_0)$. Here, $J^{n-1} = \partial I^n-I^{n-1}$.

Comment: I see.  Yes, most likely, $I^0$ should be a point.

Comment: @Randall Yes. But here, $I^0$ shouldn't be just arbitrary point since $J^0$ depends on it.

Comment: Where does $I^0$ occur? There is no set $\pi_0(X,A,x_0)$. But in fact you have $J^0 = \{0\}$.

Comment: @PaulFrost In $\pi_1(X,A,x_0)$, $J^0$ is defined and $J^0 = \partial I^1-I^0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your definition of $J^{n-1}$ seems to be this: Set $\bar I^{n-1} = \{t_1,\ldots,t_n) \in I^n \mid t_n = 1 \}$ and $J^{n-1} = \text{cl}(I^n \setminus \bar I^{n-1})$. This shows that $J^0 = \{0\}$ since $\bar I^{0} = \{1\}$. So your interpretation is correct. Note that some authors define  $\bar I^{n-1} = \{t_1,\ldots,t_n) \in I^n \mid t_n = 0 \}$ which produces not the same $J^{n-1}$ as above. But that is irrelevant for the exact sequence.
2. The last three terms of your sequence are no groups, but only pointed sets. The concept of exactness for sequences of pointed sets is nevertheless introduced by the usual "$\operatorname{ker}-\operatorname{im}$"-definiton. To verify $\operatorname{ker} \partial \subset \operatorname{im} j_*$, consider $[f] \in \operatorname{ker} \partial$, where $f : (I,\{0,1\}, \{0\}) \to (X,A, x_0)$. This means that $[f \circ \iota]$ is the trivial element in $\pi_0(A)$, where $\iota : \{1\} \hookrightarrow I$. In other words, $f(1)$ lies in the path component of $x_0$ in $A$. Hence $f$ is homotopic via a homotopy of triples to a map $f' : (I,\{0,1\}, \{0\}) \to (X,A, x_0)$ such that $f'(1) = x_0$. Therefore $f' : (I,\{0,1\}) \to (X,x_0)$ and by definition $j_*([f']) = [f'] = [f]$.
3. $\pi_0(Y,y_0)$ is the set of homotopy classes of maps $g : \{1\} \to Y$ with basepoint being the homotopy classe of $c_{y_0} : \{1\} \to Y, 1 \mapsto y_0$. It can be naturally identified with the set of path compenents of $Y$.
   $\operatorname{ker} i_*$ is the set of all $[g] \in \pi_0(A,x_0)$ such that $[i \circ g]$ represents the basepoint in $\pi_0(X,x_0)$. This means that $g(1)$ is contained in the path component of $x_0$ in $X$.
   Let $[f] \in \pi_1(X,A,x_0)$, where $f : (I,\{0,1\}, \{0\}) \to (X,A, x_0)$. Then $i_*(\partial ([f])) = [i \circ f \circ \iota]$. But clearly $i \circ f \circ \iota(1)$ lies in the path component of $x_0$ in $X$. Thus $i_* \circ \partial$ maps $\pi_1(X,A,x_0)$ to the basepoint, i.e. we have $\operatorname{im} \partial \subset \operatorname{ker} i_*$. Next consider $[g] \in  \operatorname{ker} i_*$, where $g : \{1\} \to A$ . This means that $g(1)$ lies in the path component of $x_0$ in $X$. Take any path $f : I \to X$ such that $f(0) = x_0$ and $f(1) = g(1)$. Clearly $f$ is a map of triples $(I,\{0,1\},\{0\}) \to (X,A,x_0)$ and by construction $f \circ \iota = g$. Thus $[g] \in \operatorname{im} \partial$-